# Can I input into an array without knowing its size? Other ways of storing unknown input size?(C)

Tags: c, arrays, input

I need to create a program that receives grades and then does things like average and median etc. The input will be of the grades one after the other and will end when -1 is inputted. I cant know how many grades will be inputted beforehand. How can I do this efficiently? Can I make it an array even if I dont know how many objects there will be? I cant use vectors or such, its not in the material allowed. If its not possible, how can I do it otherwise? 
Thanks

Comment: What is there in the "material allowed"? What have you tried so far?

Comment: The `malloc` family of functions is usually used for that. Or just a static array, where you return an error if the number of grades exceeds the size of the array.

Comment: I'm allowed to use arrays, loops and conditional statements. I tried using a loop (while input!=-1) but I'm not completely sure where to go from there...

Comment: Have you already studied dynamical allocation of memory and functions like [realloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc)? Otherwise follow Downvoter's suggestion.

Comment: What do you mean by vectors?

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamically allocated memory. Not sure if that is considered allowed in your case though. An array wouldn't do; when a problem states "we don't know how many inputs we'll get", without any estimate of a reasonable maximum, this means anything with a predetermined size will be wrong.

Do you really need to store all the data somewhere? What else do you need to calculate besides average and median? If you have an actual collection, you'll need to sort it to find the median and this is pretty expensive.

Think about alternative ways to approach this.

Average is easy, divide the sum of grades by the count; no need to keep any specific grade input to do that.

As for the median, since we're talking about grades, I presume they cannot be just any number, right? They are probably whole numbers between 1 and 4, or perhaps you might have 1.5, but not 1.25? It depends on the input restrictions, but if you can only have grades of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 for example, why not create an array of six elements and just count the occurrence of each grade. Knowing the total grades entered, you can find the median.

Comment: Problem is the grades are between 0-100. The commands I need are average, median, max grade, min grade, percentage of grades above or beneath a certain grade, and creating a factor so that a certain percentage of grades will pass a certain grade. Because of all this it seems that I need to store the data, don't I?

Comment: Are the grades integers? If so, you can work with an array of size 100 and do what I suggested. Max and min are easy, as well as average. The median is an issue in case the grades can be any real number. Not sure about the last part with the factor, depends on what exactly you'll be doing with the data.